# Promises under the hood (call stack, Web API, task queue)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise, synchronous

I read a lot of articles about promises. I know that promise executions are microtasks for task queue, async code executions are tasks for task queue. How does it happen in promises that after asynchronous code works synchronous code (i.e. after some fetch we can write synchronous code in .then block)?
I guess that all code inside promises use callstack (if sync code inside Promise body) or task queue (if async code inside Promise body). I saw a lot of examples with callstack, Web API and task queue with setTimeout code but how it works with promises I can only assume.
Can you show on my examples what happens with callstack, Web API and task queue, please?

**First example:**

```
const promiseWithAsyncBody = new Promise(resolve=> 
setTimeout(()=> resolve('resolved'), 0));
promiseWithAsyncBody.then(msg=> console.log(msg));
```

I guess that promise body gets into task queue, then it gets into in callstack, when code come into setTimeout, setTimeout gets into WebAPI and immediately gets into task queue but at the same moment .then block gets into the task queue. After that triggers setTimeout and only after setTimeout triggering .then block.

**Second example:**

```
const promiseWithSyncBody = new Promise(resolve=> resolve('resolved'));
promiseWithAsyncBody.then(msg=> console.log(msg));
```

I guess that promise body executes in callstack and till that executes .then block gets into the task queue. When callstack is empty, .then block executes.

Am I right? Explain in more details who knows please. Thank you!

Comment: All `then` is, is a callback.  there is no separate callstack, Javascript is single threaded.  All tasks are just processed in an event loop, and the only difference between a normal task & a microtask  is that microtasks will get executed in a single event loop, were as a normal tasks might wait until next tick,  the reason we have a difference is because JS is single threaded to prevent UI locking up normal tasks use the next tick, but because micro tasks by nature are meant to be tiny, doing then bulk should not effect the main thread too much.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a promise

```
const promise = new Promise(/*executorFunction*/ (resolve, reject) =>
   {/* executor function body */}
)
```

the body of `executorFuncton` is being executed right away.
Inside the body of executor function you may or may not call some asynchronous api's.

After a promise is just created it is in "pending" state.
If inside of executor function resolve callback is called, the promise's state becomes "fulfilled" (or it may became "rejected" if reject callback is called).

And only after the promise become fulfilled a microtask is crated (which wraps a callback you've provided in `then()` call) and pushed into microtask queue by browser.
The observable difference between task queue and microtask is that tasks in microtask queue always
run before tasks in task queue. And that's the only clear info about microtask and task queue I found on the internet when I was interested in this topic too.